# Querying sales, grouped by weeks

Tags: sql, sqlite, fmdb

I'm trying to put together a query in SQLLite for my app and wanted to ask for a little help please.

The query I want to write:

"I'm a user with UserID x. For my personal work week, which can start on any day D that I want (Sunday to Saturday, Monday to Sunday, etc), I'd like to see which work week was my worst, which was my best, in terms of sales.

To keep it simple "worst" and "best" simply means the highest and lowest sales summed for that week.

If everyone's work week started on Sunday, this is easy, but this is not the case. I have to overcome a SQL challenge of grouping all of the rows in the database table not just by week, but a custom week (users define which day starts and ends the week).

As an example, if my work week starts on Sunday, then this past week, the week of May 28th is a Sunday and is the beginning of my work week (and it ends this Saturday June 3rd). I would follow this pattern for all records in the table.

However, a different user could have their work week start on Monday, May 29th, and end on Friday, June 2nd.

So this means for user 1, I'd want to group his rows from the starting day of Sunday, and the ending day of Saturday (and then aggregate them all, and take the first and last records for sales).

For user 2, however, I'd want to group his records in the date ranges of Monday to Sunday

Here is where I'm at so far. I'm close I think.

(Note that I store the date as a unix timestamp in milliseconds, hence the division by 1000 and the unixepoch part). The +d part is actually an integer based on the start of the day, but I haven't figured out what that number should really be. Just when I think I get it, it fails for someone else's day.

```
SELECT 'Date', SUM(Amount) 'Amount'  
FROM Sales WHERE UserID = x
GROUP BY CAST(( julianday((datetime(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) + d) / 7 ) AS INT)
```

Does anyone think they could give me a hand? :)

Thanks so much!

**EDIT**

Thank you so much for your help!

For the +d question (what should the value 'd' be to offset)?
Here is what I found after testing, and this works as far as I can tell. I understand Sqllite uses 0 as Sunday, 1 as Monday, etc, and I understand we were grouping and dividing by 7 (for 7 days in the week), but any idea why these would be the right values for 'd' as the offset? It seems to be working now. I see the pattern goes 2,1,0,6,5,4,3 but kinda strange order to go in eh?

```
if (day == Sunday) //if your work week starts on Sunday, d=2
     return 2
else if (day == Monday)
     return 1
else if (day == Tuesday)
     return 0
else if (day == Wednesday) 
     return 6
else if (day == Thursday) 
     return 5
else if (day == Friday) 
     return 4
else if (day == Saturday) 
     return 3
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. a `.dump` of a suitably tailored toy database.

Comment: 2,1,0,6,5,4,3 is not that strange. We are adding the numbers 0 to 6 to the Julian day number. When we add 0 we start with a Tuesday obviously. So when we add one more, we start on day earlier, i.e. Monday. That goes on till adding six to start with Wednesday. Write the number 2,1,0,6,5,4,3 in a circle and you'll see they are all contiguous. If we added 7, we would start with Tuesday again, by the way, so we can add 7 (or 14 or 21 or -7 etc. for that matter) to any of these numbers. So we could just as well add the numbers 9,8,7,6,5,4,3 instead or subtract 5,6,7,8,9,10,11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

1. You are adding `d` to the datetime. I don't know whether this actually adds days. I could not find out what happens if you add an integer to a datetime in SQLite. To play it save, add the day to the julian day instead. You don't have to first get a datetime and from this the julian day by the way, you can do that in one step:

   ```
   julianday(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') + d
   ```

   This is the only real flaw I see in your query.
2. the Julian day is a fractional number such as 2457907.5. When you invoke a division with `/` on it, you get a fractional result. I see that you convert this result to `INT`, but I would suggest to convert to INT first and only then divide which would make this an integer division implicitly.

   cast(julianday(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') + d as int) / 7

   This is just for readability; I get a day number (2457907 rather than some decimal 2457907.5) and integer-divide by 7 (e.g. 2457907 / 7 = 351129).

The whole query:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(DATE(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS from_date, 
  MAX(DATE(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS till_date, 
  SUM(Amount) AS total
FROM Sales 
WHERE UserID = x
GROUP BY CAST(JULIANDAY(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') + d as INT) / 7
ORDER BY SUM(Amount);
```

`from_date` and `till_date` don't always represent the full seven days though, but only the worked days (e.g. in a week from Sunday to Saturday, but worked only Monday, Wednesday and Friday, it would show the dates for Monday and Friday). It would take slightly more work to show the real week. (I better don't try this now, for it's so easy to be one day off, when not being able to try the query.)

**EDIT:** Here is my try on the start and end days of the weeks. When we invoke `DATE` on a floating point value, this value is considered a Julian day. (Maybe it would work with the integer, too, I can not be sure from the documentation.)

```
SELECT 
  DATE(CAST(CAST(JULIANDAY(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') + d as INT) / 7 as REAL)) AS from_date,
  DATE(CAST(CAST(JULIANDAY(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') + d as INT) / 7 as REAL), '+6 day') AS till_date,
  MIN(DATE(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS first_working_day, 
  MAX(DATE(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS last_working_day, 
  SUM(Amount) AS total
FROM Sales 
WHERE UserID = x
GROUP BY CAST(JULIANDAY(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') + d as INT) / 7
ORDER BY SUM(Amount);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this! In the dev database i'm running this against, a particular user starts his day on Sunday 5/28, and ends on Sat 6/2 (today). He only worked 3 days that week. When I ran the above query, it seemed to do as you said and considered the days worked but not the full week. I played with the +d part (+0, +1, .., +7) and it certainly showed different results, but not aggregated correctly. I'll keep playing with this but thanks for your support! If you have any other suggestions and don't mind, I'd love to get some more help from you. Thank you sir!

Comment: That should be correct. The whole week *is* considered in this query (only the real week starts and ends are not shown; you'd have to calculate them from your group by formula somehow). You can edit your question and show results (just some five rows) where you think one or more of the result rows are incorrect.

Comment: I've added a query that should hopefully properly state the weeks' starts and ends.

Comment: I've updated the ORDER BY clause, so you see the worst week first and the best week last in your results. If you want to limit your results to only these two lines, you'd probably have to use `UNION ALL` with the query twice, once with `ORDER BY SUM(Amount) LIMIT 1` and once with `ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Thorsten thanks so much for your help. I had a small question above in my edited question. If you can shed any light on why it works the way it does, that would be awesome for the sake of completeness :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try to execute below query:

```
select 
  min(to_char(to_date(order_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'Day'))
    keep(dense_rank first order by sum(sales) desc) best_day,
  min(to_char(to_date(order_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'Day'))
    keep(dense_rank last order by sum(sales) desc)worst_day
from orders
where userid=x
group by to_char(to_date(order_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'Day');
```

Comment: wow thanks. The only thing is i'm getting near "(": syntax error:  so it's not running. Your parenthesis seem matched to me.. I put spaces after the naming of the columns, and even put your 'worst_day' and 'best_day' in quotes but it still throws that syntax error. Any ideas what error might be happening near the ( ?

Comment: is it possible 'keep' isn't a valid SQLLITE statement?

Comment: This is an Oracle query. It doesn't work in SQLite. And it wouldn't in Oracle, for that matter given that the gouping is on days here rather than weeks.

Comment: May I know why it would not work in oracle, As it is running in oracle

Comment: You group by day. How could this result in sums per week? (Apart from that, what gives you the idea that the date is stored as a string formatted 'mm/dd/yyyy'?)